# Whats wrong in my subsequence validation?

Tags: python, for-loop, append, sequence

I am trying to get this function to check if the list SEQUENCE is subsequence of list ARRAY. Subsequence means: must have all the numbers and they must be at the same order. In the exemple below SEQUENCE is a subsequence of ARRAY.
array=[5, 1, 22, 25, 6, -1, 8, 10]
sequence= [1, 6, -1, 10]

Can anyone tell me why my code doesnt work?

```
array=[5, 1, 22, 25, 6, -1, 8, 10] 
sequence= [1, 6, -1, 10]

def isValidSubsequence(array, sequence):
arrayValid=[]
if len(array) >= len(sequence):
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        numSeq = sequence[i]
        for j in range(i, len(array)):
            numArr = array[j]
            if numSeq==numArr:
                arrayValid.append(numArr)
                array.remove(numArr)
            else:
                array.remove(numArr)
    if arrayValid==sequence:
        return True
    else:
        return False
else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop on j (`for j in range(i, len(array)):`) starts at an index that corresponds to a position in sequence.  Advancing through array must be independent of the index of values in sequence.

You can do this with an iterator:

```
array=[5, 1, 22, 25, 6, -1, 8, 10] 
sequence= [1, 6, -1, 10]

iArray = iter(array)
isSubsequence = all(s in iArray for s in sequence)

print(isSubsequence) # True
```

The `s in iArray` part advances the iterator (iArray) up to the point where s is found.  If array contains all the elements of sequence in the same order, then every s in sequence will be able to advance to a matching value in iArray.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

```
public static boolean isValidSubsequence(List<Integer> array, List<Integer> sequence) {
    int sqInt = 0, arInt = 0;
        while (sqInt < sequence.size() && arInt < array.size()) {

            if (sequence.get(sqInt).equals(array.get(arInt))) {
                   sqInt++;
            }
            arInt++;
        }
        return sqInt==sequence.size();
  }
```

**Solution 2**

```
public static boolean isValidSubsequence(List<Integer> array, List<Integer> sequence) {
   int sqInt=0;
        for(Integer val:array){
              if(sqInt==sequence.size()){
                    break;
                }
              if(sequence.get(sqInt).equals(val)){
                     sqInt++;
                }
        }
    return sqInt==sequence.size();
  }
```

**Solution 3**

```
public static boolean isValidSubsequence(List<Integer> array, List<Integer> sequence) {
     int sqInt=0;
        for(Integer val:array){
              if(sqInt==sequence.size()){
                    break;
                }
              if(sequence.contains(val)){
                     sqInt++;
                }
        }
    return sqInt==sequence.size();
  }
```